# Reading from a locked SQLite3 database

Tags: c, objective-c, sqlite

I am looking at a SQLite database owned by a third party process. It appears locked and has a *-journal file. What I don't know, is if the lock is shared or exclusive.

I am hoping to read from the database even though it is currently locked by that other process. I will only ever read from the database.

Currently I fail at this. I get a SQLITE_BUSY return code as long as the third party process is running.

I have looked at sqlite3_busy_handler, but that does not appear to be the solution. From what I understand that only allows for implementing a retry mechanism. It doesn't seem to offer a way to just ignore the fact, that the database is locked.

How can I force SQLite into reading from that database?

BTW, I am currently using the FMDatabase API wrapper. This does not use sqlite3_busy_handler. It loops endlessly as long as it gets a SQLITE_BUSY return code.

Comment: How did you open the database?

Comment: int err = sqlite3_open( databasePath, &db );

Are there other ways?

Comment: Do you have any way of telling if the other process is defunct or in disk sleep (likely) ? The lock (AFAIK) should be exclusive only for writing.

Comment: The other process is alive and well. From SQLite documentation, I understand SQLite would try to use the journal to roll back before letting me read.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've been doing some research on this and it looks like there are some (very undesirable) options.

- Kill the process that has the database locked

This probably isn't an option for you and it isn't for me either.

- Copy the file and read the copy

This seems to be the best solution to this problem.  In my case I'm trying to read a Firefox sqlite database.  Firefox appears to lock the file for long periods of time so I can't just wait.

Because you are copying a live database file you could get a corrupted copy. I don't think there is risk of corrupting the original (but I'm not sure about this).

Simply copy the file on the shell like

```
copy original.sqlite copy.sqlite
```

or

```
cp  original.sqlite copy.sqlite
```

Then open as normal.

Comment: Sorry, I had forgotten about this SO question. I ended up cloning the Lightroom database before reading: https://github.com/karelia/iMedia/blob/master/IMBLightroom3Parser.m

Comment: Sounds like you came to the same conclusion. Thanks for the update.